# Change Title Bar Colour SwiftUI (No NavigationView nor .ignoresSafeArea())

Tags: swiftui

There are two solutions I have seen can be used to change the colour of the title bar in SwiftUI:

- Making the use of `NavigationView`
- Ignoring the sage area with `.ignoresSafeArea()`

I have no use for a `NavigationView` nor I want to use `.ignoresSafeArea()` since it helps on giving the `TabView` bottom tab space.

The only requirement to the solution I am looking for is that it cannot be for iOS 16 and above only, since it will not be viable to use in production for at least the next two years.

**TL;DR:**
I need to change the colour of the title bar (the upper-most part of the app) with features available in versions prior to iOS 16, and without the use of `NavigationView` and `.ignoresSafeArea()`

The white stuff in this image:

[image]

Comment: Sounds feasible @rid. Would I do that with GeometryReader?

Comment: You use `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)` to only ignore the top safe area

Comment: I used a ZStack and made one of its memebers a color that .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top), it works, is that a good idea tho? @NoeOnJupiter and @ rid

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't be.

Comment: Both comments from @NoeOnJupiter are right, you should try both.